# Monodroid swipe

Tags: android, xamarin.android, viewflipper

I need to implement swipe for my application. Meanwhile i find lots of examples on how to do this in Android, it's quite the opposite with Monodroid. I'm having problems converting java code to c# and the mondroid documentation is just crap! Cant find anything about onFling or similar approaches.

Anyone that can point me in the right direction, maybe a tutorial or code snippet?

My plan is to use a viewflipper with the swipe detection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may be what you want, it allows you to swipe left and right to change views:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Spot on mate! Am i allowed to use this in commercial applications?

Comment: I will mark this as a right answer if no one comes up with a easier solution, without having to use custom made libraries.

Comment: Yes, it's the Apache license, which is extremely liberal.